# Port a local python program into a Jupyter notebook and run it in Colab

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I have a local python program used for research purposes.

- I would like to convert it in the form of a Jupyter Notebook
- Then, I would like to share it with Colab, so that my colleagues can execute it

Is there a standard and smooth way to do this?

The link to the program is here: https://github.com/alessioferrari/VoiceBiofeedEmo

Comment: Why don't you just clone the repository inside the colab, and follow the steps. You can run any python script inside colab too.

Comment: Thanks a lot A. Dg, I will try this one!